# Should I add third party data to web application database?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping

I have a Django application that users fill in some background information, such as "graduated university". These fields are optional, so for some users, they can be empty.

Given that, I have another service that crawls the web for the missing information. **This service is completely decoupled from the Django application**. It has its own schedule and saves the scraped data to S3 as JSON periodically.

The Django application has admin pages that summarize user information. For these pages, I need to use the real application data which is stored in the application database, as well as the scraped data that resides in S3.

Currently, I have a Django model named `ScrapedUser` that has a JSON field named `data`. To populate this model, I manually sync it with the data in S3. (Download files from S3 and create a `ScrapedUser` instance with it etc.)

My question is, to use those different data sources together, **should I populate my real user data in the application database with the third party data that I scraped from the web**?

In other words, I wonder if it would be better to map scraped information at `ScrapedUser` to the real `User` model.

To better illustrate it, here is a mocked version of the architecture:

I have a standard `User` model and a `ScrapedUser`.

```py
# models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
  ...
  university = CharField(...)

class ScrapedUser(Model):
  user = ForeignKey(to="User", ...)
  data = JSONField(...)
```

They look like this in the database

*User*

| id | university |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Harvard |
| 2 | NULL |

*ScrapedUser*

| user_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | {"university": "UC Berkeley", ...} |

**The final report I would like to see in the admin page**

| user_id | university |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Harvard |
| 2 | UC Berkeley |

**At the end**, should I keep these tables separate and use Django QuerySet features to merge them on view side? Or replace NULL fields in `User.university` with `ScrapedUser.data['university']`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to add the third party information to your database. If you don't, and the data remains resident in s3, which means every time you need to run a repost, the admin would have to fetch from s3 and process it.

In addition, instead of storing the information from s3 as a single field in ScrapedUser (you have stored it as 'data'), I would 'unpack' that information into fields in the ScrapedUser model.

```
class ScrapedUser(Model):   
user = ForeignKey(to="User", related_name="scrapped_info")   
university = CharField(...)
twitter = CharField(...)
facebook = CharField(...)
...
```

This would make the processing of the information much easier at a later date.
So given the related_name (as shown above), you can easily fetch the information like this:

```
user = User.objects.create()
user.scrapped_info.university
```

This displays the university information that was scraped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jmgutu. I will consider it.